# How do I report user stories that are active more than a sprint?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, agile, scrum, sprint

I am looking for a way to report active user stories for more than a sprint. We practice sprint planning by selecting groomed user stories from the product backlog into sprint backlog and aim to complete those during the sprint. Sometimes, the team picks up user stories and keeps them active for more than a sprint, which is not our practice. How do we report such user stories? The logic I am looking for is from the first sprint; a user story is active to the last sprint; it is in the active state. I looked at the lead time and cycle time charts, but they did not provide specific insight into for above scenario.

Ideally, we would like a user story completed within a single sprint (Col 2). However, sometimes we have a user story span across multiple sprints (Col 3 or Col 4). My question would be, how do I report such User Stories? Unfortunately, we have many teams, and it is not possible to review every team's work items.

[image]

Comment: `We practice sprint planning by selecting groomed user stories from product backlog into sprint backlog and aim to complete those during the sprint.` About this , can you give detailed guidance? It would be better if you could attach some screenshots.This will help me understand your issue.

Comment: Thanks Hugh Lin for the comment. I have updated the question with additional information. Let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , you can get the userstory with active state in the current spirit(Sprint 4), and then filter the userstory by `Create Data`. The userstory with the `Created Date` before the sprint(Sprint1) start date should span multiple sprints.

Example in query:

[image]

According to the query, you can generate the report.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a story can not be delivered in a sprint, try to break it down into several stories or even one story with several subtasks.
Or split the story in a follow-up story, describe what was implemented and leave the rest for the follow-up.